# Preservation of universes in presheaves

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, type-theory

In [Lifting Grothendieck universes](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/NOTES/lift.pdf) Hofmann and Streicher construct a universe in the category of presheaves over a small category given a Grothendieck universe in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Suppose now I have two small categories $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$, a functor $\mathfrak{f} : \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}}$ and a universe $u : E \to V$ in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}}$ that is closed under the formation of dependent products, sums and W-types.

What conditions on $\mathfrak{f}$ are sufficient to ensure that $\mathfrak{f}(u) : \mathfrak{f}(E) \to \mathfrak{f}(V)$ is a universe in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}}$ that is closed under the same constructions?

I am mostly interested in the case where $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ are posets, if this makes anything easier.